# Why is EF automatically running the seed method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, seeding

We use ASP .NET to create API-driven CMSes. Occasionally we need to fill the database with default data and use EF’s seed method for this purpose. I understand that seed is called when we run update-database in the Nuget Package Manager console and also when we deploy, but for some reason our seed method seems to be calling itself once the project has been deployed on the server. We use an Azure App Service to host our CMSes.

Does anyone know how to turn this auto-seeding behavior off? We haven’t noticed a defined pattern in terms of timing, only noticing that it’s happened after our database has been reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to do something with the migrations, however i don't know why you're updating the database manually, you could use migrations for that matter.

1- Go to Nuget Package Manager console.

2- Enable-Migrations.

3- Set the configuration method to Automatic migrations and data loss.

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

4- Leave the seed method empty

```
protected override void Seed(Yourproject.DAL.Yourdbcontext)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
    }
```

Try this if it's what you're looking for.

Good luck

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I should have provided more detail. We are already using migrations to make any changes to our models. The problem arises when we leave our seed method uncommented. This in turn leads to the seed method running at seemingly random times on the server and reinitializing all our data. It's this behavior that we are looking to stop. Commenting out all of the code in the seed method effectively accomplishes this for us, but we would like to understand why the seed method is running of its own accord even without us triggering it with a publish.